# How to add a column to the grid that shows value from another screen in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I'm new to Acumatica, could you please help me? I have too screens IN202500 (stock items) and SO301000(sales orders). I added a field to stock items and now I need to show a value from that field in grid column of sale orders for each stock items. I suppose that I need to use PXDefault attribute for this?

Comment: Yes. or you can add it during row defaulting / row selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this.  I'll provide 3 possibilities.

1. If your View used by the grid contains InventoryItem, you may be able simply to select your custom field from InventoryItem and add it directly to the screen.  I'll assume this is not an option or you likely would have found it already.
2. Create a custom field in a DAC extension on SOLine where you add your custom field as unbound (PXString, not PXDBString) and then use PXDBScalar or PXFormula to populate it.  I haven't used PXDBScalar or PXFormula to retrieve a value from a DAC Extension, so I'll leave it to you to research.  I do know this is super easy if you were pulling a value directly from InventoryItem, so worth doing the research.
3. Create as an unbound field as in #2, but populate it in the SOLine_RowSelecting event. This is similar to JvD's suggestion, but I'd go with RowSelecting because it is the point where the cache data is being built.  RowSelected should be reserved, in general, for controlling the UI experience once the record is already in the cache.  Keep in mind that this will require using a new PXConnectionScope, as Acuminator will advise and help you add.  (Shown in example.)  In a pinch, this is how I would do it if I don't have time to sort out the generally simpler solution provided as option 2.

Code for Option 3:

```
#region SOLine_RowSelecting
protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelecting<SOLine> e)
{
    SOLine row = (SOLine)e.Row;

    if (row == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    using (new PXConnectionScope())
    {
        SOLineExt rowExt = row.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();

        InventoryItem item = SelectFrom<InventoryItem>
            .Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
            .View.Select(Base, row.InventoryID);

        InventoryItemExt itemExt = item.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();
        rowExt.UsrSSMyDatAField = itemExt.UsrSSMyDataField;
    }
}
#endregion
```